# Performance impact of using jackrabbit to store static content like images and read them using servlet and stream as an image to the user?

Tags: java, servlets, jackrabbit, jcr

I want to use apache jackrabbit to store static content of a web page (mostly images) and want to deliver it to the user using a servlet whenever a request come to the server for an image.
My question is do you see any performance impact of this. As every time a request hit the server i will login connection with apache jackrabbit and deliver images (content) to the user as a servlet response. More code here :[How to store images to jackrabbit and deliver those images to HTML pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394609/how-to-store-images-to-jackrabbit-and-deliver-those-images-to-html-pages)

**Note:** I donot want to use apache HTTP Server and manually handle storing of images and retrieval and unauthenticated download of resources.

Comment: Why? JCR's strength is structured or versioned content. Not images.

Comment: Wrong - JCR allows for binary properties which work well for storing images and other binaries. That's assuming the performance of the underlying implementation is adequate, so Rajesh's question makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating JCR sessions on [Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/) is cheap in terms of performance, and if you use the [DataStore](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore) there's a quite direct path from the the on-disk binary stream to the response socket, assuming your application doesn't add any extra layers.

That being said, this is something that I would measure myself, in my own environment - serve images both with a plain HTTP server and with your app on Jackrabbit, saturate the servers with enough client requests and check what you get.